# Wait for user to click on an independent 2fa link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you get a JavaScript/JQuery page to "be informed" when an external link is clicked?

Specifically, looking to verify e-mail addresses in the manner that many sign-ups or two factor Authentication (2FA) schemes do. I want to popup a dialog box, saying "I've sent an email to x@y.com, go click that link to verify that is you".

When the user clicks on the link I can update the database to say that x@y.com is now verified ... but how do I notify the open dialog box window to continue?

Do you poll with AJAX calls?  Or open an AJAX call which polls on the server?  Or this there a cool way of notifying the JavaScript in the browser that the event has occurred?  Or have to provide a button to say "I've done that now"?

-Monathan

Comment: Polling with AJAX calls is absolutely doable, and so is having a "done" button that sends the AJAX call. Both of those are easy and completely fair solutions. There are also ways for the server to talk to the browser -- "notifying the JavaScript", as you say. This is called WebSockets (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). There are plenty of libraries that can help you with this, most notably https://socket.io/ on NodeJS. What language is your server in? I can help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Nisala - the backend is PHP (LAMP in fact)... Thanks, Monathan

Comment: It's been a while since I've done anything in PHP, but I think the standard for WebSockets in PHP is Ratchet. http://socketo.me/ Ratchet has a tutorial on their site, and here's another one that's probably good: https://www.twilio.com/blog/create-php-websocket-server-build-real-time-even-driven-application

Comment: Again, you can absolutely do AJAX polling or a button, and especially with a language like PHP, that'll likely be easier to set up -- but if this type of server-event-driven stuff will be important in other parts of your application, it'll be worth it to figure this out.

Comment: Having read those references, I see what you mean.  Thanks for the advice and guidance and background information!